# mysqli_query gives null result php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to interrogate a database, but mysqli_query($dbc, $query) always returns `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}` 
I do not have any var_dump in the code.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    trigger_error ('Could not connect to MySql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "it had an error";
} else {
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
    echo "it connected";
}
```

this echoes "it connected"

```
function getGames($dbc){           
    $query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE min_players <= ".$number." AND max_players >=".$number.";";         
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\ n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return "no affected rows";
    }
}
```

When I run my query in phpMyAdmin, I get several lines of results.

Also, the function doesn't return "no affected rows" when it is called:

```
$result = getGames($dbc);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: I don't see where `$number` comes from...

Comment: this is a web service, i get it through a $_POST value earlier, actually the whole query is built differently than in here, but i didn't post everything, as that works (checked it with echo)

Comment: Well, have you tried `mysqli_fetch_assoc` on that query result...?

Comment: yes, it worked with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` .. i just realized, i wasn't fetching my `mysqli_result` object

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're declaring `$number` globally, [it won't be available in the scope of `getGames`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You should pass it in:

```
function getGames($dbc, $number) {
    // ...
```

Additionally, you could output the exact `SQL` that you're running so you can test it in phpMyAdmin (and so you can verify that `$number` is correctly being passed to your function):

```
echo $query;
```

Finally, [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) doesn't return the number of rows in `SELECT` statements. Try [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead:

```
$sql = sprintf('Your SELECT statement with %d number', $number);
echo $sql; // To visually verify the SQL is valid

$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

if (false !== $query) {
    return mysqli_num_rows($query);
} else {
    return mysqli_error($dbc);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. indeed, i wasn't using the right methods to handle data, i wasn't fetching the result anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed  your mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) to mysqli_num_rows($result), and works for me. 
*mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)*  Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

function getGames($dbc){
    $query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE min_players <= ".$number." AND max_players >=".$number.";";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\ n
MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    return $result;
} else {
    return "no affected rows";
}
```

}